# how to handle else part in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, python-2.7

Hi I have a code below and want to put 'N/A' in CSV if there is no key is present.
tried adding else part after if but getting added N/A values at the end of each row. Can anyone suggest how to handle this.

```
def pods():
api = '/v1/pods'
response = callapi(api)
test = []
for i in response['items']:
    if 'pod' in i['metadata'].keys():
        podname=i['metadata']['pod']
    for container in i['spec']['containers']:
       for key, value in container.items():
           if key == 'image':
               row_values = []
               containerimage = value
               row_values.append(podname)
               row_values.append(containerimage)
           else:
             row_values.append("N/A")
           if key == 'name':
               containername = value
               row_values.insert(1, containername)
               test.append(row_values)

with open('pod.csv', 'w', newline="") as write_obj:
   csvwriter=csv.writer(write_obj)
   for i in test:
     csvwriter.writerow(i)
```

tried adding else part like above, not working properly-getting added "N/A" values at the end of each row in csv

I'm getting output like

podname1,containerimage,containername,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
podname1,containerimage2,containername2,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A

Comment: Check your indentation! 
The above looks wrong. It will execute the last row always, its not under the Else statement

Comment: What does 'response' look like? Your if-conditions are clearly not triggered so perhaps your iterating over the wrong iterable in your response.

Comment: If your `else` clause was improperly indented then the interpreter might have considered it to be not part of the `if` but part of the `for`. (Yes,  in Python `for` can have an `else`.) But without correctly indented code it's impossible to be sure.